# background image not showing in IE8 when putting it on a repeat declaration

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8, background

I have a background image that I only want on my home page, so I have the .home class on the body tag. Works fine in everything except ie8 and ie9. It's not an image problem, because if I move the image css to the first wrapper declaration it works fine... but then would appear on every page. I could declare it for all wrappers then put background: none; for every other page but that's really messy. I feel I'm missing something really obvious here.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 940px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.home .wrapper {
    background-image: url(../images/home-illustration.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 100px;
}
```

The page is here: http://mcging.4pixels.co.uk/index.html

Comment: Thank you, that's sorted it. Just didn't make sense why IE works in a different way.

Comment: Where do I do that? Sorry haven't asked a question for quite a while.

Comment: On the left side of my answer there is a checkmark, just check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you can shorten your css like so:

```
background: url(../images/home-illustration.png) no-repeat 0px 100px;
```

second,
on the homepage `wrapper` div put `class="wrapper home clearfix"`

your actual css should be:

```
.wrapper.home{
    background: url(../images/home-illustration.png) no-repeat 0px 100px;
}
```

Comment: `.home.wrapper` would work too - but just make sure there's no space between them like posted above.